# What exactly does px represent in web font size

Tags: html, css

I'm doing some graphics (in Javascript, if that's relevant), and I know you can size fonts with `pt`, `px`, `%`, etc. When looking up what `px` means, every site seems to have the same vague answer -- the size of the font in pixels. I'm wondering what *exactly* `px` represents. For example, if I have `20px`, will 20 pixels represent the height of a capital `A`, a small `e`, a lowercase `g` or the difference between the bottom of the `g` and the top of the `A`?   (I'm assuming it's the size of the `A`, but I just want to double check).

Furthermore, `px` is apparently relative to the view size. So if I do a `fillRect(1,1,20,20)`, will this be the size of a capital A at 20px, or does the font size change on different devices independent of the graphics?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> For example, if I have 20px, will 20 pixels represent the height of a
>   capital A, a small e, a lowercase g or the difference between the
>   bottom of the g and the top of the A?

None of them. It represent an abstract object called the "em-square". The height of capitals, the width of the glyphs, and various other measures of the glyphs are then defined in each font as proportional to the em-square. But often, none of the measures you see is exactly equal to 1 em-square size, or in your case, equal to 20px.

Comment: So, if I wanted to estimate the height of say a captial A in Arial, how would I do it?  (or more consisely, if I wanted to draw a capital A that's 20 pixels high...)

Comment: You have to look at the font metrics. TrueType fonts, for example, can be inspected in TypeLight 3.2. The font metrics give a unit size for the em-square (typically 2048 or 1000) and a caps height in the same units (e.g. 1466) so for capital height of 20px, you'd set the font-size to (20px * 2048 / 1466)

Answer (score 1):

per http://www.unitconversion.org/typography/pixels-x-to-centimeters-conversion.html

10 pixels are 0.264583333 CM.

other than that, it can very depending on your font and the display resolution of the screen.

Comment: Hmm... maybe I wasn't clear in my question...   I just tried drawing a capital A in my javascript program (ctx.fillText("A", 100, 100), and I did a ctx.fillRect(120,100,20,20), and they're not the same height -- the A is not quite 20 pixels hight --  so what does the 20 in 20 px mean???

Answer (score 0):

No, the size of one pixel `px` is not officially defined in a technical way.

*Although I cannot tell you who exactly defines the value, if it's the pc-manufacturer or who it is and whether w3 guidelines tell these specifying parties to measure it from a certain distance depending on screen size, But* the most specific and most helpful description of the "magic" `px` unit is

## 1 px equals the smallest width to make a line visible on the specific device.

given that the watching user stands at a device relative reasonable distance.

(see [Official w3 Info about the px unit](https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/units.en.html#:%7E:text=The%20px%20unit%20is%20the,(no%20anti-aliasing).)).

Comment: I agree that this makes the unit a bit tricky to use, if you decide to at all.