# Is size of a pixel relative to the screen size?

Tags: css, pixel

I am creating a website that is mobile friendly. I've defined a fixed size for all buttons.

```
.btn
  min-height:45px
```

When moving from a large screen to a small screen does the size of the pixel scale? For instance, if on a large desktop screen, 45px takes up 1% of screen height will it also take up 1% of screen height on a small mobile screen? It looks like it doesnt scale proportionally to the height of the screen. Should I be going about this a different way? Thanks!

Comment: 45px won't take up the same percentage of screen height, no. There's more of an effort to make it a size that's roughly similar at standard viewing distance for that type of screen. It's complicated by the fact that people can *choose* a resolution on desktop monitors, or select accessibility features that increase pixel size. **You should not be worrying this much about exact pixel heights anyways**.

Comment: More on the technical aspects of pixels... https://www.techopedia.com/definition/24012/pixel

Comment: There is also a difference between physical pixels and CSS pixels. Search for "CSS pixel", "window.devicePixelRatio", "Retina display", "Pixel DPI" and of course "wiki pixel" to get started if you want to dig into the subject.

Comment: I think Prosy Arceno answer is more complete and should be the Chosen correct answer, no this one. Consider changing your accepted answer to better guide new users.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. It is not. If you want to scale your web app, you should use relative units like `%`, `vw`, or `vh`.

You can read more about it [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp).

And you can study how to view your web app on different sized viewports [here](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/device-mode/#viewport).

Comment: This should be the correct answer in my own honest opinion.

Answer (score 2):

No, pixels are not relative to screen size. If you want to use a relative suffix, use [the `%` suffix](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/percentage). This will make the style **relative to the parent element.** For example, if the parent element is the `<body>` element, then `width: 100%` will make the element's width the size of the page.

Answer (score 0):

No, a pixel does not scale. If you would like your html elements to scale, use vw (view width) and vh (view height) instead of px (pixels).

Comment: This could have used more explanations? Consider improving your answer with examples, guides and links to resources.

Answer (score 0):

This varies from one device to another.

`Px` is in no way non-visually comparable to any relative units like `vh`, `vw`, `%` etc etc.

[If you want to know what `px` means as exact as possible see here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74112023/14824067)